# Is it possible to download ipa-file from TestFlight?

Tags: ios, curl, testflight, ipa

If I am a beta tester of any app, how can I download ipa from TestFlight?

I made it in HockeyApp via API:

```
 curl -o app.ipa -H "X-HockeyAppToken: $TOKEN" -O -L "https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/$APP_ID/app_versions/$BUILD_NUMBER?format=ipa"
```

Maybe someone knows how do it in TestFlight?

Answer (score 6):

No. Not possible.
You can't download it.

Comment: is it possible to extract the TF ipa from iPhone after installing it from test flight ?